# Mobilefirst with Microsoft SQL Data source fails to start more than one app

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, ibm-mobilefirst

when having a Liberty profile with more than one project WAR which also relies on Microsoft JDBC driver (sqljdbc4.jar) as its Mobile first platform database. if you try to load the two WARs in the same server.xml there will be a Microsoft security exception. something about using "Integrated Security=true;" or alike

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

you should connect the MSSQL library to the application as a common reference like this:

```html
<library id="worklight-jee-lib">                                                                                                
        <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/jee" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>                                  
        <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.1.jar"/>                               
</library>                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                   
<library id="MSSQL">                                                                                                           
                <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/mssql" includes="sqljdbc4.jar"/>                                              
</library>


 <application id="your_app_ID" name="YourAppName" location="myproj.war" type="war">                                     
        <classloader delegation="parentLast" commonLibraryRef="worklight-jee-lib,MSSQL">                                            
        </classloader>                                                                                                             
 </application> 
<application id="your_app_ID2" name="YourAppName2" location="myproj2.war" type="war">                                     
    <classloader delegation="parentLast" commonLibraryRef="worklight-jee-lib,MSSQL">                                            
    </classloader>                                                                                                             
 </application>
```